# protobuf-dt not working on Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, protocol-buffers, xtext, eclipse-luna

Installed protobuf-dt from the marketplace on Eclipse 4.4.2. When I attempt to open the editor or access the Protocol Buffers' preferences in settings I get the following error:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org/eclipse/xtext/ui/shared/SharedStateModule
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by installing [Xtext](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/xtext) and restarting Eclipse.